# Cascading picker without using range and count?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to do a cascading picker where the second picker is populated from an array of vehicle models depending on the first picker of vehicle makes. The data comes from a JSON file in my bundle. This is how I load the vehicle makes:

```
Picker("Make", selection: $vehicle.vehicleMake) {
    ForEach(Manufacturer.allManufacturers) { index in
        Text(index.make)
    }
}
```

That works, but I'm unsure how to add a second picker based on its selection. I thought I would have to do something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vehicle: Vehicle
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Make", selection: $vehicle.vehicleMake) {
            ForEach(0..<Manufacturer.allManufacturers.count) { index in
                Text(Manufacturer.allManufacturers[index].make)
            }
        }
        Picker("Model", selection: $vehicle.vehicleModel) {
            ForEach(Manufacturer.allManufacturers[vehicle.vehicleModel].models.count) { index in
                Text(Manufacturer.allManufacturers[vehicle.vehicleModel].models[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that has all sorts of issues. vehicleMake and vehicleModel are String types and Xcode expects Int. Is there a way to do it without using range and count?

I also clean up the nil coalescing in Core Data like this:

```
mport Foundation

extension Vehicle {
    
    var vehicleMake: String {
        get { make ?? "" }
        set { make = newValue }
    }

    var vehicleModel: String {
        get { model ?? "" }
        set { model = newValue }
    }
}
```

The Manufacturer struct:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Manufacturer: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { make }
    var make: String
    var models: [String]

    static let allManufacturers = Bundle.main.decode("Manufacturers.json", as: [Manufacturer].self)
    static let example = allManufacturers[0]
}
```

Here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "make": "Toyota",
    "models": ["Corolla", "Camry", "RAV4"]
  },
  {
    "make": "Honda",
    "models": ["Civic", "Accord", "CR-V"]
  },
  {
    "make": "Ford",
    "models": ["Mustang", "F-150", "Explorer"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using 2 `selection` var,
to have the second Picker depends on the first Picker selection.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PickerView()
    }
}

struct PickerView: View {
    @State var modelSelection = "Corolla"
    @State var makeSelection = Manufacturer.allManufacturers.first ?? Manufacturer(make: "", models: [])
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55){
            Picker("Make", selection: $makeSelection) {
                ForEach(Manufacturer.allManufacturers) { maker in
                    Text(maker.make).tag(maker)
                }
            }
            Picker("Model", selection: $modelSelection) {
                ForEach(makeSelection.models, id: \.self) { model in
                    Text(model).tag(model)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Manufacturer: Decodable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var make: String
    var models: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case make,models
    }

    // for testing
    static let allManufacturers = [Manufacturer(make: "Toyota", models: ["Corolla", "Camry", "RAV4"]), Manufacturer(make: "Honda", models: ["Civic", "Accord", "CR-V"]), Manufacturer(make: "Ford", models: ["Mustang", "F-150", "Explorer"])]
    //Bundle.main.decode("Manufacturers.json", as: [Manufacturer].self)
}
```